# Lock certain pages for logged in users

Tags: php

I have this function below that tells the cms which pages a guest can visit and which pages a logged in user can visit. I have tried to find a better way and I havent really found and better ways to do it, but I am almost sure that this can't be the best way... is there any better way to do this?

```
final public function handleCall($k)
    {
        global $users, $_CONFIG;

        if($_CONFIG['hotel']['in_maint'] == false)
        {
            if(!$_SESSION['user_id'])
            {
                switch($k)
                {
                    case "index":
                    case null:
                        $users->login();
                    break;

                    case "register":
                    $users->register();
                    break;

                    case "forgot":
                        $users->forgotten();
                    break;

                    default:
                        header('Location: '.$_CONFIG['hotel']['url'].'/index');
                        exit;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                switch($k)
                {
                    case "index":
                    case null:
                        header('Location: '.$_CONFIG['hotel']['url'].'/home');
                    exit;
                    break;

                    case "register":
                    header('Location: '.$_CONFIG['hotel']['url'].'/home');
                    exit;
                    break;

                    case "forgot":
                        header('Location: '.$_CONFIG['hotel']['url'].'/home');
                        exit;
                    break;

                    case "help":
                        $users->help();
                    break;

                    case "account":
                        $users->updateAccount();
                    break;

                    default:
                        //nothing
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            header('Location: '.$_CONFIG['hotel']['url'].'/maintenance');
            exit;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see why you can't use this. You can create a separate PHP page to put this code so all you need to do is call the page that houses it instead of inserting all of this code on each page of your website.

Comment: Because it is not the fastest.

Comment: First make it work. Then make it fast. Looking at your code, I see plenty of potential to improve it, starting with `global`.